I want a button to appear in the fifth second of the video html5
I have a video tag. I want to appear a button 'next' When 5 seconds have passed from the video. Below code but not work.


<script>
var vid1 = document.getElementById("MyVid1");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.style.display = "none";

vid1.play();


if(vid1.currentTime==5){
btn.style.display = "block";}
</script>
<video width="320" height="240" id="MyVid1" controls >
  <source src="vid/1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 
</video>

<button id='btn' >tryit</button>




Look into the timeupdate event

the main issues with your code are: 1 - if(vid1.currentTime==5) is tested once and once only, and it's just after the code that begins the playback. 2 - even if that code were to run more than once, how likely is it that the playback time is exactly 5 (and not 5.001 or some other value close but not equal to exactly 5)

Instead of checking .currentTime just once, you can set an event listener on the timeupdate event and check .currentTime whenever it is fired.
var vid1 = document.getElementById("MyVid1");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.style.display = "none";

vid1.play();

// EDIT Check the .currentTime whenever the timeupdate event is fired
vid1.addEventListener( "timeupdate", event => {
  if( vid1.currentTime > 5.0 ) btn.style.display = "block";
} )

